# Automatic backup of WDMyCloud hard drive to FTP

Tags: hard-drive, backup, script, ftp

I have a WDMyCloud network hard drive at home which I use to backup the various phones and computers of the family. I would like to use an extra level of backup by synchronizing this with a remote FTP server (whether it is Dropbox, Google drive, etc.)

I understand there is no on-the-shelf solution for this, but would it be possible to write a script, copy it on the network drive and run it from there -> ie let the copy process run on the WDMyCloud without having to keep other computers open?

Also I would like to have a backup system that only updates changes to avoid sending all the data on every backup (something like SVN does for code). Is it possible to write such a script?

Answer (score 1):

## Not Really

I've got a MyCloud.  It runs on some kind of read-only Linux.  You can enable SSH to it, but any changes you make that way disappear after a reboot.  I couldn't get cron working either, so no scheduled jobs.  I ended up keeping some scripts in a network share (so that they persisted) and running them manually from time to time.

I suppose you could set up a low-powered, always-on computer (like a raspberry pi) and manage it from cron on there.  Dropbox has an [API](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/07/stack-overflow-documentation-for-dropbox-apis/) that you might be able to use in scripts.